# Database query speed

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, batch-file

I have a php script which runs continuously several hours and every few seconds I have new data to save in a database. So I have the option to store new data when it becomes available or gather them in an array and save them once I have 100 or 500. If I'm correct php cannot send multiple insert queries to the database so the two options above would take the exact same amount of time to save.

Am I wrong or one is faster than the other? Perhaps there is a third solution faster than these?

Comment: Just curious, did you end up using LOAD DATA INFILE or multi-record INSERTs?

Comment: multi insert. every second is precious so I didn't want to waste time writing a file then reading it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following syntax to insert multiple rows at a time:

```
INSERT INTO foo
( a, b, c)
VALUES
( 1, 2, 3),
( 4, 5, 6),
( 7, 8, 9)
```

or, you could dump the data to a delimited file as you get it and when you get to 100 or so lines in the file use LOAD DATA INFILE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) to do the insert.  I've found that LOAD DATA INFILE is very efficient for importing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Neither would be faster. But if you use bulk insert and wrap the inserts in a transaction, it will be significantly faster.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
COMMIT;
```

This will only work if the storange engine allows transactions. So better use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand the offline batch stored procedure option. This way you will:

- Save the connection times that happen every script call otherwise (I'm assuming so, but I didn't see your scripts)
- Save the communication time between php and mysql
- Save the parse interpretation, since all datas will be processed within the sql engine at once

rgds.